# estimating eblupfh model: Error in median.default(vardir) : need numeric data

Tags: r, vector, statistics, syntax-error

When I am running syntax error masseage is shown "Error in median.default(vardir) : need numeric data"

Syntax:
`library(sae) eblupFH <- eblupFH(formula   = income ~ urbanC + RuralC + HHsizeC + EmC + HBD1C + HBD2C + HBD3C + HBD4C + HBD5C + HBD6C + HBD7C + HBD8C + HBD9C + HBD10C + HBD11C + LivingSC + HowManyRoomsC + electricityC + heatingC + toiletC + sewerageC + bathroomC + hotwaterC + own1C + own2C + own3C + own4C + ownedlandC + ownedgardenC + femaleC + maleC + ageC + Nat1C + Nat2C + Nat3C + Nat4C + Nat5C + Nat6C + Nat7C + Nat8C + Nat9C + Nat10C + Migr1C + Migr2C + Migr3C + YearC1C + YearC2C + YearC3C + YearC4C + refugeestatusC + Edu1C + Edu2C + Edu3C + Edu4C + Edu5C + Edu6C + Edu7C + Edu8C + Edu9C + Edu10C + Edu11C + MRST1C + MRST2C + MRST3C + MRST4C + HealthstC + disabilitiesC + givematerialhelpC + takematerialhelpC + WholeLandC + numberofpicesC + grapesC + citrusesC + otherfruitsC + CattleC + BuffaloC + DonkeyC + HorseC + PigC + SheepC + GoatC + RabbitC + BeehiveC + PoultryC + tractorC + autoC, vardir  = jem, method    = "REML", MAXITER   = 100, PRECISION = 0.0001, B = 0, data=vari)`

what should be reason? I have already checked format of variance (variable name jem) and it is numeric there is not missing values and etc.
I tried: 1) changing format as in excel as in r; 2) using different variable for testing, result is same;
3) excluded variable from formula; 4) updated r studio and sae package.